# Java Sorting using first in first out (QUEUES)

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, console, queue

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Queuessorting {


    public static int randInt(int min, int max) {

        // Usually this should be a field rather than a method variable so
        // that it is not re-seeded every call.
        Random rand = new Random();

        // nextInt is normally exclusive of the top value,
        // so add 1 to make it inclusive
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

        return randomNum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> ar = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> arf = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        System.out.println("Enter n: ");
        int n = myScanner.nextInt();
        int count = 0;

        int r=0;
        for(int i = 0;i < n;i++){
            ar.add(randInt(1,99));
        }

        System.out.println(ar.size());

        for(int i=0;i<ar.size();i++)
            System.out.println(ar.get(i));
        int j=0;
        int nctr=0;

        while(ar.size() > 0){   
            int a = 0;
            int nct = 0;

            a = ar.remove(0);

            if(nctr == 0){
              temp.add(a);

            }

            else{
             if(arf.size() != 0){
                 for(int k = 0;k<arf.size();k++){
                     temp.add(arf.remove(0));
                 }
             }

             while(r<temp.size() && count == 0) {   
                if(a > temp.get(r)){
               arf.add(a);
               count++;
               nct++;
                }

                else
                    arf.add(temp.remove(0));

                r++;
             }
                  if(nct == 0)
                      arf.add(a);
            }
            if(temp.size()!=0){
                for(int l = 0;l<temp.size();l++){
                    arf.add(temp.remove(0));
                }


            }

            nctr++;
        }
        System.out.println("***************************");
        for(int u=0;u<arf.size();u++)
            System.out.println(arf.get(u));



    }


}
```

My code works perfectly fine when having an input of 2 but if I enter any number greater than 2 the sorting is completely messed up. I'am sorting descending order being the top the number the first index of the arraylist

pseudocode: example : 72,97,2 a will get 72 from ar then store it to temp because it is the first one, next a will get 97 and compare it to 72 if a > 72, a will go to arf then the remaining values in temp will go to arf too : 92,72 <- contents of arf now. After that procedure everything in arf will go to temp and the loop goes on and on I hope you understand my explanation :(

the final output or the final arf contents will be 97,72,2

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear on what exactly the sorting order you are expecting?? Is it just descending order?

Comment: Are you trying to sort using a queue as a helper data structure or are you trying to get a sorted queue?

Comment: pseudocode:
example : 72,97,2
a will get 72 from ar then store it to temp because it is the first one, next a will get 97 and compare it to 72 if a > 72, a will go to arf then the remaining values in temp will go to arf too : 92,72 <- contents of arf now. After that procedure everything in arf will go to temp and the loop goes on and on I hope you understand my explanation :(

Comment: I sort of understand what your trying to say. What I understand is that you have a temporary array that will hold values and when a new value is entered, it is compared against the other values in temp and is added to an arraylist in sorted order. If this is the case, it is possible that your comparing of variables with a single integer against the temporary array is wrong. If not, can you explain why you must need to use a queue for sorting and I might find a simple way to do it.

Comment: it is for "experimental programming" as our homework